# An issue on Windows Server 2003/IIS6: what's a good procedure to hunt down ASP/ASP.NET production issues?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

I've been an admin of IIS servers for a short time now. Often I'm looking at production web servers when they're having issues (mostly many classic ASP/ASP.NET (1,2,3.5,4)/SharePoint) applications running on them.

I have my procedure for narrowing down an issues, but I was curious as to what others think the best way going about tracking down production errors/slowness on IIS are?

Mine is something like:

1. Task manager open, looking for heavy memory/cpu consumption from processes
2. Open Event Viewer - Anything major going on?
3. Open IIS logs - Anything jump out at me?
4. Run a few Perf Monitors - Any good templates on there on this?
5. Open CMD and run 'netstat' see if many connections are going on,etc.

Any tools/utilities out there you trust to run in a production environment that encapsulates all of this, or is it just opening the built-in tools and getting a feel for what's going on? Any tools that can take a look at many IIS servers at once, and get an overview for these things?

Any helpful hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this SO question useful: [What are the key performance metrics to monitor for a deployed ASP.NET web application?](https://serverfault.com/questions/221135/what-are-the-key-performance-metrics-to-monitor-for-a-deployed-asp-net-web-applic)